# Range scan vs Unique Scan vs Skip Scan

Tags: sql, oracle

What does unique scan, range scan and skip scan mean?
 Can we explicitly decide which scan to use?
 What are the pros and cons of all these scans?

Comment: I never heard of "unix scan" in Oracle. I guess you mean "*unique* scan"? And PL/SQL is **only** used in stored procedures. Everything else is "just" SQL. This site might be interesting for you: http://use-the-index-luke.com All execution operations are also documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/ex_plan.htm#i23461

Comment: Yes I mean unique scan.. Thanks for clarifying, edited the post.

Comment: [This chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_optop.htm#CHDFJIJA) of the SQL Tuning Guide contains a good description of each index access method you mentioned, as well as several others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are pretty self-explanatory by their name:

- A "unique" scan scans for a single value in a unique index.
- A "range" scan starts at some starting value, and reads index entries sequentially (i,.e. along the b-tree) until it encounters a value that runs past a second value  (a search for a single value on a non-unique index is a range scan, BTW).
- A "skip" scan uses only the leading column(s) of a composite index to work out its distinct values (so, once it finds a value, it "skips" along that index until it finds the next one).

Each is appropriate (and optimal) for a given type of record matching.  The SQL optimizer almost always picks the most appropriate for a given situation (if statistics are up-to-date).